# Preprocess Field: CSS Style per page

Tags: 7, theming, hooks, entities

Trying to set up a `preprocess_field_hook()` to send a different css style depending on the node that is loaded for simpler theming. Will not work and been beating my head.

Have this set inside my `template.php`and have my tpl pages named correctly (exam: node--node_page_one.tpl.php), which is loading fine with other functions already working. I feel like I need to have it point to the actual element somehow? Or should I be doing this somewhere else like in the `preprocess_node_hook()`?

Sorry for my noobness.

```
 function mytheme_preprocess_field(&$variables, $hook) {
      $variables['fieldclass'] = '';
      switch ($variables) {
        case 'node_page_one':
          $variables['fieldclass'] = 'tiny-blue';
          break;
        case 'node_page_two':
          $variables['fieldclass'] = 'large-green';
          break;
        default:
          $variables['fieldclass'] = 'black';
          break;
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than $variables['fieldclass'] use $variables['classes_array']

[Based on the docs](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/template_preprocess_field/7)

Comment: After taking this into account and tinkering with what I had. Got it working!

`($vars['element']['#bundle'])`

For future theming, what is the best/easiest method to discovering the classes array? 

Thanks again for the help!